# AWS Secret manager does not allow me to create a secret for a RDS read-replica

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds, aws-secrets-manager

I have created a read replica for my production RDS PostgreSQL instance. I planning to use that read-replica to connect redshift federated queries. The documentation suggests creating a secret but when I go to AWS Secret Manager and try to create a new secret the replica instance is not present.

I haven't found anything that suggests that the above is not possible. In fact, having a read-replica for federated queries it is a suggested good practice. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **association** between secret manager and RDS is based only on the **format of a secret value**. The formats available are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/reference_available-rotation-templates.html#sar-template-mysql-singleuser).

In console you can do this association only for the primary db instance. But using **CLI** you can do this as well for **read-replicas**. It is useful, as read replicas have **different endpoint** then the primary instance.

For example, for MySql:

```
aws secretsmanager create-secret \
    --name read-replica-secret \
    --secret-string file:///tmp/secret.json
```

where `/tmp/secret.json` would be:

```
{
  "engine": "mysql",
  "host": "<required: read replica instance host name/resolvable DNS name>",
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "2PLvZK5Gcuht8qefK5O7",
  "dbname": "testdb",
  "port": "3306"
}
```

This way, your read-only clients can get full set of credentials from the SM, which includes **correct read-endpoint**.

But the issue is that you will have two secrets now. One for primary and the other one for reader. Which is a **management hustle**. It complicates even more if you want to have automatic rotation.